# Import CSV to SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to import a csv file to an SQLite table.

Example csv:

```
1,2
5,6
2,7
```

Example command:

```
sqlite> create table foo(a, b);
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .import test.csv foo
Error: test.csv line 1: expected 2 columns of data but found 4
```

I'm not even sure why it would find four columns with six pieces of data and two columns.

Comment: It appears that the command expects column headers in the first line, and that the line-terminator is not being recognized as such. `6 - 2 = 4`

Comment: Can I specify a line-terminator or is there one missing from my csv?

Comment: It doesn't look like you can specify the line-terminator from the SQLite command-line tool. Do you have a text-editor (like Notepad on Windows, but better) that will show you the line-terminating characters? There are three main variations: `\r\n` on Windows, `\n` on *nix (includes newer Macs), `\r` on older Macs.

Comment: I'm using BBEdit, but I don't see any of those characters at the end of the lines. I tried adding them manually, but it doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: I don't know what was wrong with what I was doing, but I just imported everything successfully using the SQLite Manager extension for Firefox. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use SQLite Expert Professional 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I import load a .sql or .csv file into sqlite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045910/how-can-i-import-load-a-sql-or-csv-file-into-sqlite)

Comment: This website can convert a CSV (or Excel) file to SQLite - http://converttosqlite.com/

Comment: You forgot the period before `separator`; it should be `.separator`.

Answer (score 209):

What also is being said in the comments, SQLite sees your input as 1, 25, 62, 7. I also had a problem with , and in my case it was solved by changing "separator ," into ".mode csv". So you could try:

```
sqlite> create table foo(a, b);
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import test.csv foo
```

The first command creates the column names for the table. However, if you want the column names inherited from the csv file, you might just ignore the first line.

--- New Versions of sqlite3 ---

The latest version of sqlite3 creates the table and columns for you if you let it.

You can also skip the line ".mode csv" if you append "--csv" to the end of the import statement like so:

`sqlite> .import test.csv foo --csv`

Comment: For other people who land here from a search, if the first line of your csv file contains the column names, then you can omit the first `create table` command and sqlite will use the column names from the csv file.

Comment: @EarlCrapstone: could you elaborate? It doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: @d33tah Look at these [examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example). Notice how the first line contains the column names `Year,Make,Model,Description,Price` and not actual data. If that's the case with your CSV file, then you do not need to manually create the table using the `create table` command. The `.import` command will use the first line in your file to determine the column names and create the table accordingly. You still have to include the _name_ of the table in the command. The same info [from the SQLite docs](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#csv).

Comment: Why are you setting `.mode`?  Isn't that only for output?

Comment: If you find that the generated table groups multiple columns together, check that you aren't using a reserved word such as `type` for a CSV column name.

Comment: For me running `.mode csv` meant my import failed, and the database file wasn't created, so I ran only the last line

Comment: @EarlCrapstone There is a problem with doing that which is that the column types will all be TEXT regardless of the type of the input data.

Comment: you can skip `.mode csv` if you append ` --csv` to the end of the last statement like so: `.import test.csv foo --csv`

Answer (score 46):

The easiest is to add the comma-separated table headers directly to your CSV file, followed by a new line, and then all your CSV data.

In the SQLite shell enter:

```
$ sqlite3 yourfile.sqlite
sqlite>  .mode csv
sqlite>  .import test.csv yourtable
sqlite>  .exit
```

Comment: How to handle `unescaped " character` alerts?

Comment: If you create a table before importing, then it will not look for headers.

Comment: I have to put file in same folder where sqlite3.exe is located. Can i use another path for csv file ?

Comment: Minor point: "If you haven't got Sqlite installed on your Mac" ... AFAIK it is installed by default.

Comment: All columns are text columns. If quantitative data perhaps less work to type in the table definition beforehand, although the open source GUI tool "DB Browser for SQLite" can alter column types on the fly.

Comment: Tried brew install sqlite3

FormulaUnavailableError: No available formula with the name "/usr/local/opt/python@2/.brew/python@2.rb".

Answer (score 34):

Here's how I did it.

- Make/Convert csv file to be seperated by tabs (\t) AND not enclosed by any quotes (sqlite interprets quotes literally - says old docs)
- Enter the sqlite shell of the db to which the data needs to be added

  `sqlite> .separator "\t" ---IMPORTANT! should be in double quotes
   sqlite> .import afile.csv tablename-to-import-to`

Comment: for multiple rows, my tsv needed to specify the ROW separator with this command
 `.separator "\t" "\r"`

Comment: When discussing file formats, tsv != csv

See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Answer (score 20):

How to import csv file to sqlite3

1. Create database

   ```
   sqlite3 NYC.db
   ```
2. Set the mode & tablename

   ```
   .mode csv tripdata
   ```
3. Import the csv file data to sqlite3

   ```
   .import yellow_tripdata_2017-01.csv tripdata
   ```
4. Find tables

   ```
   .tables
   ```
5. Find your table schema

   ```
   .schema tripdata
   ```
6. Find table data

   ```
   select * from tripdata limit 10;
   ```
7. Count the number of rows in the table

   ```
   select count (*) from tripdata;
   ```

Answer (score 9):

before .import command, type ".mode csv"

Quote from [Importing files as CSV or other formats](https://sqlite.com/cli.html#importing_files_as_csv_or_other_formats)

> Note that it may be important to set the "mode" before running the
> ".import" command. This is prudent to prevent the command-line shell
> from trying to interpret the input file text as some format other than
> how the file is structured. If the --csv or --ascii options are used,
> they control import input delimiters.

And

> To import data with arbitrary delimiters and no quoting, first set
> ascii mode (".mode ascii"), then set the field and record delimiters
> using the ".separators" command. This will suppress dequoting. Upon
> ".import", the data will be split into fields and records according to
> the delimiters so specified.

Comment: .mode is for output only

Comment: Apparently not so.  From the .import doc section: Note that it is important to set the "mode" to "csv" before running the ".import" command. This is necessary to prevent the command-line shell from trying to interpret the input file text as some other format.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly same problem (on OS X Maverics 10.9.1 with SQLite3 3.7.13, but I don't think SQLite is  related to the cause). I tried to import csv data saved from MS Excel 2011, which btw. uses `';'` as columns separator. I found out that csv file from Excel still uses newline character from Mac OS 9 times, changing it to unix newline solved the problem. AFAIR BBEdit has a command for this, as well as Sublime Text 2.

Comment: It's easier to use `tr -s '\r' '\n'` and that will work with all sorts of random files.

Comment: sed, tr, and other unix text processing tools are perfect for this job. They already exist on OSX, Linux, BSD, Plan9, and WSL. Not everyone is going to have Sublime or OSX and should be able to use the tools provided by the OS.

Answer (score 3):

With [termsql](/questions/tagged/termsql) you can do it in one line:

`termsql -i mycsvfile.CSV -d ',' -c 'a,b' -t 'foo' -o mynewdatabase.db`

From [Termsql](https://github.com/tobimensch/termsql)

> Convert text from a file or from stdin into SQL table and query it
> instantly. Uses sqlite as backend. The idea is to make SQL into a tool
> on the command line or in scripts.

Termsql requires [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3)

Comment: link was broken, changed it to the github repo - please clarify!

Comment: please explain why readers should use yet another two tools as the question is originally about sqlite itself and that sqlite can parse standard SQL directly from STDIN (e.g a unix pipe such as echo `.import mydata.csv foo --csv | sqlite3 mynewdatabase.db`).

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had to see the file I was trying to add, it had headers and the separator was a semicolon `;`.

I tried first:

```
.mode csv
.import myfile.csv mytable
```

But it didn't work, so I tried:

```
.separator ";"
.import myfile.csv mytable
```

And it did work, so I had to set the separator manually.

Answer (score 1):

As some websites and other article specifies, its simple have a look to this one.
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-import-csv/

We don't need to specify the separator for `csv` file, because csv means comma separated.

`sqlite> .separator ,` no need of this line.

```
sqlite> create table cities(name, population);
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .import c:/sqlite/city_no_header.csv cities
```

This will work flawlessly :)

PS: My cities.csv with header.

```
name,population
Abilene,115930
Akron,217074
Albany,93994
Albuquerque,448607
Alexandria,128283
Allentown,106632
Amarillo,173627
Anaheim,328014
```

Comment: Don't forget to run `.save someFileName` in the end. Took me hour to find this to finally export this in memory database file to disk 

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:-

1] sqlite3 name

2] .mode csv tablename

3] .import Filename.csv tablename

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had a similar problem the lines in the csv file did contain a `\n` instead of an actual a `CRLF` (line break).

```
     Alias, Name, Agency\n
     007  , James Bond, MI5\n
     Q    , Mister Q, MI6\n
     Moneypenny, Miss Moneypenny, MI5\n
```

From [Common Format and MIME Type for Comma-Separated Values (CSV) Files](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-2)

> 1. Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line
>    break (CRLF).  For example:
>
>    `aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF`
>
>    `zzz,yyy,xxx CRLF`
> 2. The last record in the file may or may not have an ending line
>    break.  For example:
>
>    `aaa,bbb,ccc CRLF`
>
>    `zzz,yyy,xxx`

After i replaced the line separators `\n` with a line break (using SHIFT+ENTER in vs code) the import under windows was possible using

```bash
c:\Apps\SQLite\sqlite_3.40.1>sqlite3.exe
                SQLite version 3.40.1 2022-12-28 14:03:47
                Enter ".help" for usage hints.
                Connected to a transient in-memory database.
                Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open C:/csv/myDataCRLF.db
sqlite> .import --csv C:/csv/source_file_crlf.csv myTable
sqlite> .save C:/csv/myDataCRLF.db
                Error: database is locked
sqlite> .save C:/csv/myDataCRLF_2.db
```

The database file `myDataCRLF_2.db` has now a table `myTable` with the records from the csv-file.