# Insert data from excel to sql table

Tags: sql, excel, sqlite, import, dbeaver

I have an SQL database that contains a table with 5 rows (and 4 columns). I need to import a very long table (100+ rows, same number of columns) that I have created in Excel. Is there an easy, quick way to do this 'paste'-like operation?

Comment: What flavour of SQL database?

Comment: Right, sorry. It's SQLite and I am using the open soure dBeaver to view/edit it. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439885/export-data-from-excel-to-sqlite-database?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa  Seems there is .import statement

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server Managment

1. Right Click on the DB Name in the solution explorer
2. Select Tasks-> Import Data
3. In the opened wizard choose 'Microsoft Excel' as data source
4. Select the excel file path and the excel version
5. Clisk next and choose the destination table details
6. Finish