# Import csv with pycharm database tool

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, pycharm

[image]I'm working with pycharm on windows and want to import a csv file into a preexisting sqllite table. I've tried variations of:

```
.import test.csv foo
```

based on [Import CSV to SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947916/import-csv-to-sqlite) , but this is not recognized. Also I don't see an answer in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/database-tool-window.html

Can this be done?