# Insert multiple rows using execute

Tags: python, sqlite

I wish to execute the following statement:

```
c.execute('INSERT INTO artists (name, score) VALUES("Buddy Rich", 10), ("Candido", 9), ("Charlie Byrd", 8);')
```

but instead of hardcoding the values as above, I have them in a variable:

```
scores = (("Buddy Rich", 10), ("Candido", 9), ("Charlie Byrd", 8))
```

how do I use `scores` with `execute()`, where `scores` could contain any number of values?

**UPDATE**

I wish to be able to guarantee that if the data is inserted into the table, that all the data, or none of the data, is inserted even if there is a program crash. If there is a program crash while running `executemany`, is there a risk that only some of the rows get added?

For example, can this result in only some of the rows being added:

```
try:
   c.executemany('INSERT INTO artists (name, score) VALUES (?, ?)', scores)
except:
   c.commit()
```

Comment: But you have still hard-coded them. `c.executemany('INSERT INTO artists (name, score) VALUES (?, ?)', scores)`

Comment: @roganjosh Does this simply execute insert multiple times (executing execute in a for loop) or is it a "multi insert" as recently introduced to sqlite?

Comment: Can you link me to what you're referring to please?

Comment: you can & should use executemany from python, just wrap it in a transaction. the other option is to load data into a table from csv: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947916/import-csv-to-sqlite

Comment: @roganjosh https://stackoverflow.com/a/1609688/607846

Comment: I wouldn't really call an 8 yr old question "recently" :P But I can't find from the docs exactly how `executemany` is implemented in relation to that

Comment: @Haleemur Ali How do I wrap executemany in a transaction?

Comment: i posted an example of how to rollback transactions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put things into transactions you should use cursors, and a try block which rolls back if an exception is raised.

```
import sqlite3   
scores = (("Buddy Rich", 10), ("Candido", 9), ("Charlie Byrd", 8))
con = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
try:
    cur = c.cursor()
    cur.execute('create table artists (name text primary key, score int)')
    cur.executemany('INSERT INTO artists (name, score) VALUES (?, ?)', scores)
    con.commit()
except:
    con.rollback()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `executemany`:

```
scores = (("Buddy Rich", 10), ("Candido", 9), ("Charlie Byrd", 8))
c.executemany('INSERT INTO artists (name, score) VALUES (?, ?)', scores)
```

Comment: If there is a program crash while running executemany, is there a risk that only some of the rows get added? In this regard, would it be safe for me to catch exceptions in my program like KeyboardInterrupt and do a commit, or do I run the risk of only having added some rows?