# CSV file cannot be read past line 7,777,761 in a 10 million record csv

Tags: pandas, csv

I have a 10 million record CSV file that fails around 7.7 million lines.
It failed going into Excel data model, MySQL, and lastly when chunking into smaller CSVs using Pandas.

The failures have been without error messages. The process just stops. Checking the last chunked CSV file, it seems to be failing on line 7,777,761

Pandas shape() and head() show that there are 10 million records, 46 columns, and the first 5 lines look good.

Thus, I'm looking for ideas on how to solve this problem.

I used skiprows to isolate that area around line 7,777,761. I got an error message saying "there are no columns to read" or some such. Seems like the file ends right there.

Could it have been corrupted by Excel when trying (and failing) to load it into the data model?
Ih can post the script and the error message if required.

Thanks,

Tried to import to Excel Data Model
FAILED at about 7.7 mm lines
(Not sure of the cause, no error, just stopped. Something was imported but very low, like 4900 lines)

Tried to import to MySQL
FAILED at about same place, no error message, just stopped.

Experimented in Python using Pandas and confirmed
1000000 lines and 46 column
Viewed head. All went well.

After succsessfully chunking on a 10,000 line dummy CSV. . .

Chunked file into 100,000 line CSV files using Pandas
FAILED without error.
Last line was 7,777,761

Changed chunk size to 50000
FAILED, no error
last line was ID 7,777,761.

Rechunked starting at 7,777,761 mm. FAILED
but this time,d there was an error

Comment: Try dumping a few lines around the problem area into a different file, and examine those lines closely.

Comment: if you are in *nix, what does `wc -l data.csv` give you?

Comment: or `nl data.csv | grep -E '^77777[0-9]{2}'` (which should show the lines 7777700 until 7777799)

Comment: 1) Given that modern versions of Excel  have a row limit of 1,048,576 per [Excel specs](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3) I would say trying to stuff 7,777,761 into it did bad things to the data. 2) Can you get a clean version of the CSV file from the source?

Comment: Or you could try importing it into SQLite (see: [Import CSV to SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947916/import-csv-to-sqlite)). this might reveal this error near line 7777761 ....

Answer (score 1):

You could try to inspect closely the lines around the problem area. Here is a little helper function that might help:

```py
def lines_from(filename, *args):
    lines = set([i for a in args for i in ([a] if isinstance(a, int) else a)])
    buf = io.StringIO()
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
            if i in lines:
                buf.write(line)
    buf.seek(0)
    return buf
```

Example usage:

```py
with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write('x,y\n')
    for i in range(2, 30):
        f.write(f'{i},{i*2}\n')
```

Then:

```py
b = lines_from('test.csv', 1, range(9, 12))

>>> b.read()
'x,y\n9,18\n10,20\n11,22\n'

>>> pd.read_csv(lines_from('test.csv', 1, range(9, 12)))
    x   y
0   9  18
1  10  20
2  11  22
```

Comment: Thanks to all. Am running through each suggestion.